# Discord stats bot adding old stats to embed

Tags: statistics, discord, bots, counter, solution

So the problem is I´m making a CS:GO stats Discord bot, and every time you use !stats + Steam ID it gives you your stats in an embed. The first time you do it, it works perfectly, but after that every person that uses the command gets back his stats and the stats of everyone else that has used it previously.[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29QoP.jpg)

Essential code:

```
if (command === "stats") {
    let stats = [];
    if (stats) {
    stats = [];
    
    
    let steamID = args[0];
    if (!steamID) return message.channel.send("Negative! You haven't added your Steam ID");
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUserStats/GetUserStatsForGame/v0002/?appid=730&key=${steamWebApiKey}&steamid=${steamID}&format=json`
      )
      .then(async data => {
        let stats = data.data.playerstats.stats;
        let totalKills = stats[0].value;
        let totalDeaths = stats[1].value;
        let hsKills = stats[25].value;
        let totalMVP = stats[95].value;
        let KD = totalKills / totalDeaths;
        let HS = totalKills / hsKills * 100;
        let Knifekills = stats[10].value;
        embedStats
          .setTitle("CSGO Stats")
          .setColor("#FF0000")
          .addField("Total Kills", totalKills, true)
          .addField("Total Deaths", totalDeaths, true)
          .addField("Total HeadShot Kills", hsKills, true)
          .addField("MVPS", totalMVP, true)
          .addField("KD", KD.toFixed(2), true)
          .addField("Knife kills", Knifekills, true)
      })
      .catch(e => {
        if (e.response.status == "500") {
            message.channel.send("Negative! I couldn't find your stats, possible solution: set your game details as public on your Steam profile.");
        }
      });
    axios
      .get(
        `http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=${steamWebApiKey}&steamids=${steamID}&format=json`
      )
      .then(async data => {
        let user = data.data.response.players;
        embedStats
          .setThumbnail(user[0].avatarmedium)
          .setDescription(`[${user[0].personaname}](${user[0].profileurl})`)
          await message.channel.send(embedStats);
      })
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seems to have a minimal reproducible example, as I can't find the definitions of `embedStats` and `arg[0]`, but it seems on using the `addField()` method, you are just "inserting" new info in that `embedStats` variable, that is not being "reseted" on new requests of your Discord users. I would suggest try to "free" the variable after the execution of the command is finished, or instantiating a new one before all the `addField()` logic.

Comment: Hey there, I´ve already found the solution, I was putting my stats variable "const embedStats = new Discord.MessageEmbed();" at the start of the code and not inside the command itself, it was that simple. Thanks anyways.

Comment: So the same instance was being updated. I recommend you to tag it as a solution, so people can learn by this thread.

Comment: Sure            ------------------------------------------------------

Answer (score 0):

I´ve already found the solution, I was putting my stats variable "const embedStats = new Discord.MessageEmbed();" at the start of the code and not inside the command itself, it was that simple.